# Verify pem certificate chain using openssl

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to write a code which receives a `pcap` file as an input and returns invalid certificates from it.

I have parsed certificate chains, and I'm trying to verify them. 
Because I get the certificates chains out of a `pcap` the chain length are not constant (sometimes they includes only 1 certificate that is selfsigned (and valid)).

Let `cert0.pem` be the servers certificate and `certk.pem` the root CAs certificate.

According to my research online I'm trying to verify the certificate as follows:

1. Create a file `certs.pem` which contains the certificate chain in the order:
    `certk.pem`, `certk-1.pem`,... ,`cert0.pem`
2. use the command (`ca.pem` is a file containing root certificates):

   ```
   openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem certs.pem
   ```

But sometimes the verification goes wrong even for valid certificates, as in the following output:

```
C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA <br>
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate<br> 
error certs.pem: verification failed
```

please help me, how can I verify the certificate chain ?

Additionally is there a way to add a host name verification in the same line? (I have tried to add "`-verify_hostname name`" but again, the output was unexpected).

Comment: What do you mean it was unexpected? With that error the cert is probably not valid. Maybe because it's missing intermediate certs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I extracted the certificate chain from ssl handshake (from traffic to google) so the chain is complete and valid for sure.. Even though the openssl's output is "unable to get local issuer certificate".
See the attached pastebin: 
https://pastebin.com/gMQeNudu

Comment: Looking at [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/720250/openssl-verify-outputs-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235526/openssl-verify-error-20-at-0-depth-lookupunable-to-get-local-issuer-certifica) it would appear your pem doesn't have the right format. For me it jsut changed the error message.

Answer (score 1):

For remote certificate validation the error you mentioned here says that the *first* local certificate (depth 0) in your chain file that you are trying to verify namely being `certk.pem` as root CA certificate has to **exist / imported** in your local client trusted certificates store that you are performing your verification from.

> As stated at thawte.com [support site](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO7465):
>
> > This is the verification output of the Server Certificate sent by the server. The server sends its complete chain consisting of 2 certificates, one (depth 0) being the server's certificate "CN=www.yourdomain.com" and the other one being the CA certificate "CN=Thawte Server CA". As all root certificates, this certificate is self-signed.
> >
> > In order to avoid this error, your client must have a local copy of the root CA certificate in their trusted certificate store, either in CAfile of CApath.

ALSO: Consider using `-show_chain` verify option to view more details and/or errors in your certificate chain. Note that this error behavior is expected and by default when verifying a certificate from a non-trusted CA. You can check for the error codes in the openssl [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Verify(1)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, for some reason I have seen it just now.
I have not found a solution yet. My code has to run in windows environment, I have tried to run exactly the same command in Linox environment and it actuolly works, but tring to copy the certs folder (\etc\ssl\certs) from my ubuntu machine to windows and run the command with the copied folder as CApath parameter did not solve the problem
I have also tried to use `-show_chain` according to your suggestion, but the output remained unchanged...
Do you have an idea where did I go wrong ?
again, Thank you very much !

Comment: In case you are running your PEM program with your windows browser (eg: Opera, IE etc.) please see that the certificates with the erroneous response are first imported to your browser's certif. store. Not sure if that affects your program that you are writing but it should not affect the output from openssl.
Also: You can use the `-partial_chain` option if there are incomplete or erroneous certificates -during verification- in your chain file.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand you.
Verifying the chain in pairs (certk.pem<->certk-1.pem, .. cert1.pem<->cert0.pem) using `-partial_chain` works properly for all the pairs, but the problem appears only when verifying the root against the local store.
No browser alerted that the certificate chain is invalid so I conclude that the given root is in the browsers' store (even though the openssl use the given ca.pem file as a ca store). Even using the Linux complete store doesn't solve the problem (when in linux there is no problem..), do you have an idea what am I still doing wrong ?